# Uploaded image is not previewing in firebase. It's file type is blank, flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, flutter-image-picker

Unable to preview my image in firebase using flutter...

this is my firebase console screenshot.

[image]

Here is the code of Image picker service from gallery

```
Future<File?> getImageFromGallery() async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      image = File(pickedFile.path);
      return image;
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error , No Image Selected');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Getting the file using an event and then Uploading to firebase storage:

```
on<SubmitUserFormDataEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(UserFormLoadingState());

     // uploading the picture to firebase storage & get url

      File file = event.profile_image_file;

      String baseName = file.path.split('/').last;

      Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("profile_images/$baseName"); //generate a unique name

      await ref.putFile(file);
      String imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      print(imageUrl);
```

it successfully uploaded to firebase and get downloadUrl. if i click the download url in chrome,  it automatically starts downlaod, But image is not showing.. That't why i can't show it to UI.

Getting the download url I can't show the image to ui.. I want to preview my image like this. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add image extension to the file while uploading it to Firebase Storage like this

```dart
await ref.putFile(file,
SettableMetadata(
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
      ),
);
```